# How to hide files with specific extension in VSCode tree view

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I use VSCode with Unity3D and I wonder is there any way to hide/ignore/filter certain types of files, for example *.meta files in VSCode's tree view? I cant find any suitable option in settings.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They have added this feature now. Go to File->Preferences->Workspace Settings. That opens or creates the .vscode folder, and underneath it the settings.json file.

Here is a full settings.json file that shows how to exclude the .git folder, the dist folder and the node_modules folder.

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "dist": true,
        "node_modules": true
    }
}
```

Comment: File->Preferences doesn't seem to exist anymore (at least on the MacOS version of VSCode). Simply go to Settings, then search for 'exclude' and you'll see the Files:Exclude setting. You can add patterns there in the GUI rather than having to edit settings.json directly.

Answer (score 9):

Not at this time, but you can vote for the feature at the [Visual Studio Code User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7755693-filter-files-shown-in-folder-view).

Comment: I am happy to say that this feature is planned for the next update (post 0.3.0)

Answer (score 1):

> F1 > Preferences:Open Workspace Settings > [search settings] exclude >
>   Files:Exclude > Add Pattern

In other words, press F1 to open the thingy search thing, to find `Preferences:Open Workspace Settings`, then in the next search box, search for 'exclude', and add the pattern to exclude in the `Files:Exclude` section.

For example, to exclude all hidden backup files in Linux -- i.e. files with a tilde '~' on the end, add the pattern `**/*~`.

You might want to exclude the same pattern from the `Search:Exclude` and `Files:Watcher Exclude` sections.